# Azure Storage Exception while creating a container : Null InputStream is not a valid argument

Tags: java, maven, azure

i have created an OSGI bundle and deployed on karaf which uploads file to Azure blob.(lets say B1)
i also have another bundle for some other functionality.(lets say B2)

now when i deploy B1 alone it works fine and when i deploy both bundles B1 and B2, my upload bundle gives me following exception.

```
2013-08-26 20:09:45,633[qtp26738776-145]|DEBUG|<My_Pack>fileupload.service.uploadservice.impl.UploadServiceImpl|Exception while uploading a file java.lan
g.IllegalArgumentException: Null InputStream is not a valid argument
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null InputStream is not a valid argument
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:595)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:309)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.Utility.createXMLStreamReaderFromStream(Utility.java:327)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.implementation.StorageErrorResponse.<init>(StorageErrorResponse.java:59)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.StorageException.getErrorDetailsFromRequest(StorageException.java:54)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:85)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.implementation.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:147)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer.createIfNotExist(CloudBlobContainer.java:339)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer.createIfNotExist(CloudBlobContainer.java:257)
        at <My_Pack>fileupload.service.uploadservice.impl.UploadServiceAzureProcess.uploadFileWithDetails(UploadServiceAzureProcess.java:82)
        at <My_Pack>fileupload.service.uploadservice.impl.UploadServiceImpl.uploadFile(UploadServiceImpl.java:143)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:355)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:319)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1040)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:976)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:931)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:992)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

following is my code from where i am getting that exception.

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

```
            // Create the container if it does not exist. NOTE: The container name must be lower case.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);

            container.createIfNotExist();
            logger.debug("Uploading...");
            uploadMyBlob(container.getName(),blobClient,fileName,fileSize,stream);
            logger.debug("Uploaded...");
```

i am getting exception from `container.createIfNotExist();` i tried searching for the cause and i came across [this](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/297) but unable to find a solution:(

following is my pom dependencies xml for B1

```
    <dependencies>

    <!-- Microsoft related dependencies START -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.windowsazure</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-windowsazure-api</artifactId>
            <version>${com.microsoft.windowsazure.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

 <!-- i tried adding following too
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Microsoft related dependencies END -->

        <!--  Other dependencies START -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.ws.rs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Other dependencies END -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>
                            <My_Pack>.fileupload.service.uploadService
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;version="1.9.2",
                            com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client<!-- ;version="0.4.2" -->,
                            com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage<!-- ;version="0.4.2" -->,
                            javax.servlet.http;version="2.4", 
                            javax.ws.rs;version="2.0-m02",
                            javax.ws.rs.core;version="2.0-m02",
                            org.apache.commons.fileupload;version="1.2.1",
                            org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk;version="1.2.1",
                            org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet;version="1.2.1",
                            org.slf4j;version="1.6.0",
                            org.springframework.beans.factory.config
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Embed-Dependency>
                            <!-- jackson-jaxrs -->
                        </Embed-Dependency>
                        <Bundle-ClassPath>.</Bundle-ClassPath>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

following is pom dependency for bundle B2

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- WSO2 Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.securevault</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.securevault</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End of WSO2 dependencies -->

    <!-- Apache dependencies for WSO2 -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11.wso2v2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.wso2v5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axiom.om.util</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.wso2v2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.wso2v4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0-wso2v1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End of Apache dependecies for WSO2 -->

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End of Spring dependencies -->

    <!-- Spring OSGi framework dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-osgi-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-osgi-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.springframework.aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End of Spring OSGi framework dependencies -->

    <!-- Jackson dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End of Jackson dependencies -->

    <!-- Jasypt dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
        <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End of Jasypt dependencies -->

    <!-- Other third party dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m02</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>
                        <My_Pack>.security.*
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2.0)",
                        org.osgi.service.*;version="[1.0, 2.0)",
                        org.codehaus.jackson,
                        org.codehaus.jackson.map,
                        org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;version="1.9.7",
                        org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider;version="${org.apache.cxf.version}",
                        org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client;version="${org.apache.cxf.version}",
                        javax.ws.rs.*;version="[1.0,2)",
                        javax.xml.namespace.*,
                        org.apache.commons.httpclient.*; version="3.1.0",
                        org.xml.sax.*,
                        org.w3c.dom.*,
                        javax.xml.stream;version="1.0.1",
                        javax.xml.stream.events;version="1.0.1",
                        javax.xml.stream.util;version="1.0.1",
                        javax.xml.bind.*;version="2.1.0";resolution:=optional,
                        javax.xml.datatype,
                        javax.xml.parsers,
                        javax.xml.transform.*,
                        javax.xml.validation,
                        javax.xml.xpath,
                        javax.xml,
                        javax.sql.*,
                        *;resolution:=optional
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>
                        org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api,
                        org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub,
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub,
                        org.wso2.carbon.user.core,
                        org.wso2.carbon.user.api,
                        org.wso2.securevault,
                        axiom,
                        axis2,
                        httpcore,
                        XmlSchema,
                        neethi
                    </Embed-Dependency>
                    <Bundle-ClassPath>.</Bundle-ClassPath>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```